# geodjango + OL bbox strategy

Tags: openlayers-2, geodjango

I managed to learn the fundamentals of Django, GeoDjango and know OpenLayers for a while. Now I realize a project with a lot of objects with **point geometries**. To make the user map fast and responsive, I like to transfer only the points that are in the bounding box of the current view.

OpenLayers has on part of the solution on clientside solution with the BBOX strategy (`new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX()`) which appends the extends to the data URL e.g. `/api/node?bbox=13.898900146484,51.04243240501,13.341099853516,51.117559096132`

Now my question is, how I can **deal with that on server side**, without needing to reimplement attribute parsing and filtering on my own?
If there is no ready solution, might anybody please give me a rough snippet on what to do on django side?

Answer (score 1):

Without needing to write any code, i'm not sure. But there are many solutions that don't involve writing much code.  Im a big fan of [Django-Rest-Framework-GIS](https://github.com/djangonauts/django-rest-framework-gis), it makes writing api's that return GeoJSON very quick. It provides an InBBOX filter that can handle parsing BBOXes in the standard format, or you can provide your own get_queryset method to handle filtering.

```
def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = PointFeatureObject.objects

    bbox = self.request.GET.get('bbox')
    if bbox is not None and len(bbox) > 0:
        try:
            bbox = Polygon.from_bbox(bbox.split(','))
            queryset = queryset.filter(geometry__within=bbox)
        except Exception, e:
            logging.error("error" + str(e))

    return queryset
```

Then you will need a serializer

```
from rest_framework_gis import serializers as geo_serializers
from models import PointObjectFeature

class PointObjectFeatureSerializer(geo_serializers.GeoFeatureModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = PointObjectFeature
        geo_field = 'geometry'
```

And you'll need a view, which is well covered in [The Django Rest Framework Documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart)